# Data Gridview Not Reloading updated Data

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

I want to reload the updated record in gridview but its not working. Grid View reloads after i insert any new record but not reloads after i update the record. Although the record is saved in the Database and when i restart the application, the gridview load the updated record. I don't know why it's not reloading data when i update but reload data when i insert new record, Although i am calling the same function as i called in insertion
Here is Insert Code

```
        private void InsertEmployee()
    {

        if (tbName.Text != "" && mtbCNIC.Text != "" && cBoxBloodGroup.SelectedIndex != -1 && cBoxMaritialStatus.SelectedIndex != -1 && tbAddress.Text != "" && tbFatherName.Text != "" && cBoxGender.SelectedIndex != -1 && tbPerAddress.Text != "")
        {
                CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HRMSConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ISNULL(MAX(emp_id),0)+1 FROM EMP_Master", con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    tbID.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                    {
                        using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO EMP_Master (emp_id , emp_name,emp_fathername,emp_nic,emp_gender,emp_contact,emp_dob,emp_bloodgroup,emp_maritialstatus,emp_address,emp_per_address,emp_picture)VALUES(@emp_id , @emp_name,@emp_fathername,@emp_nic,@emp_gender,@emp_contact,@emp_dob,@emp_bloodgroup,@emp_maritialstatus,@emp_address,@emp_per_address,@emp_picture)", con))
                        {
                            //con.Open();
                            cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_id", tbID.Text);
                            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_name", tbName.Text);
                            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_fathername", tbFatherName.Text);
                            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_nic",mtbCNIC.Text);
                            //string tbMaskCNIC = mtbCNIC.Text;
                            //tbMaskCNIC = tbMaskCNIC.Replace("-","");
                            //cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_nic", int.Parse(tbMaskCNIC));
                            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@emp_gender", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                            cmd1.Parameters["@emp_gender"].Value = cBoxGender.SelectedItem;
                            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_contact", tbContact.Text);
                            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_dob", dtpBirth.Value.Date);
                            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_bloodgroup",cBoxBloodGroup.SelectedItem.ToString());
                            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_maritialstatus",cBoxMaritialStatus.SelectedItem.ToString());
                            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_address", tbAddress.Text);
                            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_per_address", tbPerAddress.Text);
                            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_picture", SaveImage());
                            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            con.Close();
                            MessageBox.Show("Record Has been Saved Successfully !", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                            FillGridView();
                            ResetForm();
                            tbName.Focus();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } 
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("All Fields are Mandatory !", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            tbName.Focus();
        }

        //catch (Exception)
        //{

        //    MessageBox.Show("Something is wrong");
        //}


    }
```

and here is the update code

```
        private void UpdateEmployee()
    {
        try
        {
            //if (tbName.Text != "" && mtbCNIC.Text != "" && tbContact.Text != "" && tbAddress.Text != "" && tbFatherName.Text != "" && cBoxBloodGroup.SelectedIndex != -1 && cBoxGender.SelectedIndex != -1 && tbPerAddress.Text != "" && dtpBirth.Text != "")
            //{
                CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HRMSConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
                {
                    {
                        using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE EMP_Master SET  emp_name=@emp_name,emp_fathername=@emp_fathername,emp_nic=@emp_nic,emp_gender=@emp_gender,emp_contact=@emp_contact,emp_dob=@emp_dob,emp_bloodgroup=@emp_bloodgroup,emp_maritialstatus=@emp_maritialstatus,emp_address=@emp_address,emp_per_address=@emp_per_address,emp_picture=@emp_picture WHERE emp_id=@emp_id", con))
                        {
                            con.Open();
                            cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_id", tbID.Text);
                            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_name", tbName.Text);
                            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_fathername", tbFatherName.Text);
                            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_nic", mtbCNIC.Text);
                            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@emp_gender", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                            cmd1.Parameters["@emp_gender"].Value = cBoxGender.SelectedItem;
                            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_contact", tbContact.Text);
                            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_dob", Convert.ToDateTime(dtpBirth.Value.ToString()));
                            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_bloodgroup", cBoxBloodGroup.SelectedItem.ToString());
                            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_maritialstatus", cBoxMaritialStatus.SelectedItem.ToString());
                            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_address", tbAddress.Text);
                            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_per_address", tbPerAddress.Text);
                            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_picture", SaveImage());             
                            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            con.Close();
                            MessageBox.Show("Record Has been Updated Successfully !", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                            FillGridView();
                            ResetForm();
                            tbName.Focus();
                        }
                    }
                }
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    MessageBox.Show("All Fields are Mandatory !", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            //    tbName.Focus();
            //}
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }


    }
```

Here is the Method for for Loading data to gridview

```
        private void FillGridView()
    {
        CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HRMSConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM EMP_Master", con))
            {
                SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                ad.Fill(dt);

            }
        }
    }
```

Is there's something wrong with my code ? i guess not because data is inserted and updated in to the database . help me please

Comment: I can't find code which bind your DataTable to GridView. It Should be someyhing like this: gridView1.DataSource = dt; in FillGridView method

Comment: @mojo there is no binding in c# winforms application

Comment: i guess you should set your Grid datasource to **dt** ?

Comment: Ok. Where your GridView populated with data. Your method  FillGridView then should be called fill DataTable.

Comment: Yeah i have already set that but i guess i missed that part while posting question.. Still not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to fill your grid view with data. And I think you should add binding in FillGridView() method:

```
private void FillGridView()
    {
        CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HRMSConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM EMP_Master", con))
            {
                SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                ad.Fill(dt);
                gridView.DataSource = dt;
                gridView.Update();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: try to add also: gridView.Update();

Comment: Does the UpdateEmployee method call on button click event?

Comment: Yeah called that Method

Comment: One comment, you should not use con.Close() because connection in using statement already.
And according to the GridView for now I don't have any idea why it is not updating. And I think that you should open connection in FillGridView method.